# Finding out stuff knowing $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2$, $\mathbf{v}_3$ and $\mathbf{v}_4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{v}_1 := \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{v}_2 := \begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{v}_3 := \begin{pmatrix}
7 \\
8 \\
9
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{v}_4 := \begin{pmatrix}
10 \\
11 \\
12
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
1. Find the reduced row echelon form $R = [\mathbf{v}_1',\mathbf{v}_2',\mathbf{v}_3',\mathbf{v}_4']$ of $A = [\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3,\mathbf{v}_4]$.
Let $A = [\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3,\mathbf{v}_4] = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 7 & 10 \\
2 & 5 & 8 & 11 \\
3 & 6 & 9 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$. So 
\begin{equation*}
R = [\mathbf{v}_1',\mathbf{v}_2',\mathbf{v}_3',\mathbf{v}_4'] = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
2. Write $\mathbf{v}_3'$ and $\mathbf{v}_4'$ as linear combinations of $\mathbf{v}_1'$ and $\mathbf{v}_2'$.
We want to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
2 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
This is when $\alpha = -1$ and $\beta = 2$. We also want to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
3 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
This is when $\alpha = -2$ and $\beta = 3$.
3. Write $\mathbf{v}_3$ and $\mathbf{v}_4$ as linear combinations of $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$. 
We want to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3
\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
7 \\
8 \\
9
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
This is when $\alpha = -1$ and $\beta = 2$. We also want to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3
\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
10 \\
11 \\
12
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
This is when $\alpha = -2$ and $\beta = 3$. Note the similarity to part 2.
4. Find all possible ways $\mathbf{v}_4$ can be written as linear combinations of $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2$ and $\mathbf{v}_3$.
Having trouble with this one. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 4, think about this way. Let $A'$ be the $3\times 3$ matrix whose columns are $\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2, \mathbf v_3$. You want to solve the system
$$A'\mathbf x = \mathbf v_4.$$
Can you see how to get the solutions from the reduced echelon form $R$ you already have?

Comment: From $R$ we see that $\mathbf{v}_1 = \mathbf{v}_3+2\mathbf{v}_4$ and $\mathbf{v}_2 = -2\mathbf{v}_3+-3\mathbf{v}_4$  with $\mathbf{v}_3$ and $\mathbf{v}_4$ being free variables.

Comment: No, those equations should be with $x_i$'s. But the vector $\mathbf x$ tells you how to take linear combinations of the *column vectors* to get $\mathbf 0$. Remember how to interpret $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$ in terms of *columns*.

Comment: Right sorry that’s what I meant I got mixed up so $v_4 = (x_3+2x_4)v_1+(-2v_3-3v_4)v_2+x_3v_3$.

Comment: You're getting closer. Note that $\mathbf v_4 = -\frac12\mathbf v_1 +\frac12\mathbf v_3$ and $\mathbf v_4 = -\frac13\mathbf v_2 -\frac23\mathbf v_3$.

Comment: So you just choose values for $x_3$ and $x_4$? Oh and my previous was wrong it should have been $-2x_3-3x_4$.

Comment: Ok so I was interpreting $R$ wrong meaning we actually have $v_4=(2-x_3)v_1+(3-2x_3)v_2+x_3v_3$.

Comment: For any $n$ we then have $v_4=(n-2)v_1+(-2n+3)v_2+nv_3$.